# C# WPF DataGrid - When adding items only blank rows appear?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm trying to add items to a DataGrid, unlike when I have used x.Items.Add(x); for a ListView it only shows blank rows. This DataGrid will only show 1 row at a time and must be editable, if you think there is a better approach rather than a DataGrid then I am open to suggestions. I've made sure the number of values matches the number of columns which was an issue to start with but it seems I am still no closer to solving this. I've tried reading many similar questions but none has solved my issue, where am I going wrong with this?

**rw_container is a blank Grid I am using to insert the DataGrid into**

```
private void AddGrid<T>(T obj) where T : ICategory
    {
        data = new DataGrid();

        PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (PropertyInfo x in props)
        {
            data.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = x.Name, Width = 100 });
        }


        //How to add the rows here?


        rw_container.Children.Add(data);
    }
```

Comment: Why don't use MVVM? That is much easier... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296399/mvvm-datagrid-binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a couple of things are missing:

DataGridColumns need `Binding` to properties:

```
new DataGridTextColumn { Header = x.Name, Width = 100, Binding = new Binding(x.Name) }
```

and DataGrid needs items:

```
data.Items.Add(obj);
```

however, much simple approach is to set ItemsSource and let Datagrid auto-generate columns:

```
{
    data = new DataGrid { ItemsSource = new[] { obj } };

    rw_container.Children.Add(data);
}
```

this way DataGrid will even create DataGridCheckBoxColumns for `bool` properties

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I am able to test this I'll respond/mark this as the solution accordingly.